# IBM x3400 upgrading to 2 x CPU Quad-Core Intel Xeon E5430

Tags: central-processing-unit, ibm, ibm-xseries

I'm trying to install two Quad-Core Intel Xeon E5430 CPUs in an IBM x3400 with an IBM M97IP motherboard.

When I turn the power on, it takes approx. 3 sec. then the fan stops and nothing happens.
After approx. 10 sec. an LED on the motherboard indicates failure of the CPU2 slot.
Even if I swap the CPUs, it still indicates failure of the CPU2 slot.
Both CPUs work individually when I start the server in either CPU1 or CPU2 slot.

I am running this server with two 835W power supply and 8 x Qimonda 2GB 2RX4 Fully Buffered ECC DDR2-667.

Answer (score 2):

For dual processors:

1. The processors must be IDENTICAL, or at least listed as compatible by the motherboard and processor manufacturer.
2. Split the RAM evenly between the two banks of DIMM slots. Do you have RAM in both banks?
3. A second processor requires a second voltage regulator. Did you install a second VRM?
4. Upgrade the firmware on the motherboard.
5. Some motherboards will work with a single quad-core processor or two dual-core processors, but not two quad-core processors. Check that your motherboard actually supports two quad-core processors.

Since you're getting a CPU 2 failure LED but it works with only one CPU in slot 2, I'm guessing your problem is either #2 or #5.

Answer (score 0):

I have here a X3400 with the M97IP motherboard. It is a IBM 7976-B2U.

This processors will not work with this server since they use the 5000p chipset. The better processor you can use on this server is 2x E5345 (80w of TDP each) or you can go with 2x X5355 (more powerful, but 120w of TDP each).